# WPF binding window title to a checkbox state

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a checkbox which looks something like this (have removed many things to make it short) -

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding functionABC, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=XYZ}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>

      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=XYZ}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Now, I have to map the window title of app to 2 different values depending on checked or unchecked. I could have done it normally, but there is a trigger set already for both states, and I don't know how to work around it.

Comment: If the title is bound to a string or something of the like why not just edit the bound string in one of the XYZ commands depending on if IsChecked's bound variable is true or not?

Comment: Not bound to anything, 2 fixed values. MS office and ms Excel for example. Right now 1 is there as title, but I gotta swap based on value of checkbox.

Comment: @tcmsh: Can't you set the source property for the title in your commands? Or what do the commands do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an special `IValueConverter`

```
public class BooleanToCustomConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public string? TrueValue { get; set; }
    public string? FalseValue { get; set; }

    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool b)
            return b ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

and use that within your Binding

```xml
<Window
  ...
  Title="{Binding functionABC, Mode=OneWay, Converter={local:BooleanToCustomConverter TrueValue='True Value', FalseValue='False Value'}}"
  ...>

  ...

</Window>
```

[sample project on github](https://github.com/SirRufo/CheckedTitle/tree/Converter)

Comment: Hi Rufo. I tried both of the approaches that you mentioned. Currently trying to use the converter method. But the converter cannot be used above declarations, ie, declaring it like  ```<converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>``` in window.resources, and modifying title at top, in window tag. I cannot modify it anywhere else because the content is already set in generic.xaml file.

Comment: And title cannot be modified in generic.xaml, as per project documents.

Comment: @tcmsh Working sample on github. Follow the link in the answer. And that `generic.xaml` is not in your question and we will **only** answer to what is asked in the question and not what is all not asked there

Comment: Apologies for that. I should have asked specifically. I did check that github link too. Btw I managed to make it run below the converter declaration. In next comment I will attach that code in case you wanna look at it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: ```<local:BaseWindow.Title>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TitleTextConverter}">
    <Binding Path="1st bool variable"/>
    <Binding Path="2nd bool variable"/>
     </MultiBinding>
     </local:BaseWindow.Title>```

Comment: Basically I was unable to properly bind it to the variable that was going to trigger change.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`

```xml
<!-- !!! remove the Title property from the Window declaration !!! -->

<Window
  ...>

  <Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding functionABC}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="True Title" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding functionABC}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="False Title" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Style>
  ...
</Window>
```

---

## Update

As [thatguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072413/wpf-binding-window-title-to-a-checkbox-state/71095774#comment125644997_71072857) suggested this style can be simplified by

```xml
<!-- !!! remove the Title property from the Window declaration !!! -->

<Window
  ...>

  <Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
      <Setter Property="Title" Value="False Title" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding functionABC}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Title" Value="True Title" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Style>
  ...
</Window>
```

[sample project on github](https://github.com/SirRufo/CheckedTitle/tree/master)

Comment: Thank you. Just 1 question. Is it necessary to bind the functionABC again in these triggers? As I have already binded in checkbox code.

Comment: How should this style trigger know when to trigger if you remove that binding? Magic?

Comment: @SirRufo You can simplify the style by removing the second `DataTrigger` and moving its `Setter` up into the style.

Comment: @SirRufo I am new to WPF, sorry. Binding is very confusing right now.

Comment: @SirRufo So the project has a separate generic.xaml file for window styling. I added the above code in that file after removing the <Window.style> tag  and title property from window declaration. But the title stays blank when debugging, whether the checkbox is checked or not.